# Putting a custom view on top of a view controller's base view, via IB

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I have got a view controller with a `UIView` and a navigation controller configured in the XIB.

Now I created a custom `UIView` and would like it to be on top of the other view. So I added a view on top of the first and changed the class to mine (`DrawableUIVIew`). None of the stuff I alter or set inside my custom view appears.

This is how I add my custom view:

[image: Screenshot of xib layout]

The custom `UIView` allows touches (which do get detected) and then draws lines (which does not happen).
Only way I could get it to draw was to use:

```
self.view = [[DrawableUIView alloc] init];
```

but that removes the nav bar and is thus useless.

How can I add a custom `UIView` above the view controller's standard view in the visual editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by simply overriding the `initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder` method inside my custom UIView

Answer (score 1):

if you are using ARC

```
[self.view addSubview:[[DrawableUIView alloc]init]];
```

if not do

```
DrawableUIView *myView = [[DrawableUIView alloc]init]];
[self.view addSubview:myView];
[myView release];
```